# usb 3-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71 - But the device doesnt exist

Tags: usb

My first question here and I'm pretty new to Linux and Ubuntu, so please go easy on me.

I'm trying to figure this out since yesterday and my situation seems to be different from the from the other ones. Or at least I think so.

Below output is going in a loop in syslog and kern.log

```
Dec 21 22:12:54 JoeGo kernel: [46897.103659] usb usb3-port4: attempt power cycle
Dec 21 22:12:55 JoeGo kernel: [46897.755658] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 70 using xhci_hcd
Dec 21 22:12:55 JoeGo kernel: [46897.755790] usb 3-4: Device not responding to setup address.
Dec 21 22:12:55 JoeGo kernel: [46897.963701] usb 3-4: Device not responding to setup address.
Dec 21 22:12:55 JoeGo kernel: [46898.171639] usb 3-4: device not accepting address 70, error -71
Dec 21 22:12:56 JoeGo kernel: [46898.303642] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 71 using xhci_hcd
Dec 21 22:12:56 JoeGo kernel: [46898.303767] usb 3-4: Device not responding to setup address.
Dec 21 22:12:56 JoeGo kernel: [46898.511667] usb 3-4: Device not responding to setup address.
Dec 21 22:12:56 JoeGo kernel: [46898.723580] usb 3-4: device not accepting address 71, error -71
Dec 21 22:12:56 JoeGo kernel: [46898.723632] usb usb3-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
```

When I check for the device in usb3-port4, it doesn't exist in lsusb and in "/sys/bus/usb/devices".

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 063: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 062: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 057: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


/sys/bus/usb/devices$ ls 
1-0:1.0  1-1:1.0  2-1      3-0:1.0  3-2:1.0  3-5      3-5:1.1  3-8:1.0  4-0:1.0  usb2  usb4
1-1      2-0:1.0  2-1:1.0  3-2      3-2:1.1  3-5:1.0  3-8      3-8:1.1  usb1     usb3
```

When I update the authorized file inside usb3 to 0, these messages are stopped. But all my USB ports becomes unusable.

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3$ ls authorized 
authorized
```

When I checked with usb-devices command, I find my Lenovo EasyCamera on Bus3 and Port 4. But this camera works fine.

usb-devices

```
T:  **Bus=03** Lev=01 Prnt=01 **Port=04** Cnt=02 Dev#= 62 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=5986 ProdID=0295 Rev=14.66
S:  Manufacturer=Vimicro corp.
S:  **Product=Lenovo EasyCamera**
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=256mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
```

in lsusb -t, camera seems to be in port 5

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 57, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 57, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 62, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
    |__ **Port 5: Dev 62, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M**
    |__ Port 8: Dev 63, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 63, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
```

I tried disabling this but updating the authorized file to 0, still that doesn't help as well.

I think my interpretation is completely wrong here. Please help!!!

Thanks!!

Comment: How often do you see these error messages? Unplug your 2/3 USB devices and see if the problem goes away. If it does, add back one USB device at a time until the error messages restart. You can use the `tail -f /var/log/syslog` to watch for new errors.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. These messages are running continuously in loop all the time. I have only my
 Keyboard connected in usb. Removing it doesn't make any difference to these messages flooding syslog.

Comment: Is there a SD card reader, and/or a built-in camera? Do they both work? Try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the errors still occur. What make/model computer?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I was on a vacation and when we returned home after a week and when I booted my laptop, surprisingly, there are no more messages. BTW, my laptop is Lenovo Ideapad Z710 and it has SD card reader and it was working fine and even the camera was working. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Pathically reset bios (jumper) was a cure form me. Gigabyte m720 us3